# Is there a word for a job title that are based on doing busy work

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, business-language

Is there a word for a job title that doesn't actually contribute to increasing productivity in an organization and is redundant, wouldn't matter if this positions were vacant and even if you make them disappear.

A loose example would be document controller working for a very small valued and magnitude project where responsibilities of this position could have been easily accomplished by a coordinator in excess to his own. but a inexperience first timer project manager (nepotism) utilized his bookish idea to employee another inexperienced incompetent document controller.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for *make-work*, e.g. a *make-work* position.

> **make-work** noun [ U ]
>
> unimportant work given to someone to keep that person busy.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-work)

Answer (score 2):

In some ways, [sinecure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sinecure) may be what you are looking for. It more has the connotation of a job that doesn't require any work but I think it could be stretched to cover jobs which provide no value.